# Unable to use router.push in Vue 3 with unplugin-vue-router dependency

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm trying to migrate a Vue 2 project to Vue 3, in the Vue 3 project It has a library named  "unplugin-vue-router" which is an Automatic file based Routing in Vue with TS support. But In the previous vue 2 (vue-router) login page It has the following method inside:

```
created() {
     if (this.loggedIn) {
        this.$router.push('/projects');
     }
}
```

So I tried to rewrite this in Vue 3:

```
onMounted(() => {
  if (loggedIn) {
    router.push('/projects');
  }
});
```

But It shows an error: **Cannot find name 'router'.ts(2304)**

So my question is how to rewrite this and make It works with vue 3, and where I can change the configuration of unplugin-vue-router.

Comment: are you using Composition API or Option API?  if you are using Composition API did you declare the router variable with 
```
const router =useRouter() 
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `composition-api router` is imported from `vue-router` plugin.

In order to use it you need to declare it as follows

```js
import { userouter } from "vue-router";

const router = useRouter();
onMounted(() => {
  if (loggedIn) {
    router.push('/projects');
  }
});
```

Check [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html) for more details.